# Maven Ant Tasks - Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, maven-ant-tasks

I am trying to set the ant build file to user Maven dependencies and I am getting error as "Failed to create task or type urn:maven-artifact-ant:localRepository

```
 package uk.co.rrv;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        System.out.println("DateTime = " + dateTime);


        System.out.println("Plus 1 hour is " + dateTime.plusHours(1));
        System.out.println("Plus 10 minutes is " + dateTime.plusMinutes(10));
        System.out.println("Plus 60 seconds is " + dateTime.plusSeconds(60));

    }
}
```

Here is my Build xml file

```
<project name="TestBuild" basedir="." default="main" xmlns:artifact="antlib:maven.artifact.ant">

    <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="Lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
    <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
             classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath"/>

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"  value="uk.co.rrv.Main"/>


    <target name="clean">
        <echo>Initializing ....</echo>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="mvn-init">
        <echo>Compling ....</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath"/>
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${log.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <echo>Building Jar ....</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

     <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <echo>Execution ....</echo>
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="mvn-init" unless="compile.classpath" xmlns:artifact="urn:maven-artifact-ant">
        <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="urn:maven-artifact-ant"
                 classpath="Lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3   .jar"/>
        <condition property="maven.repo.local" value="${maven.repo.local}" else="${user.home}/.m2/repository">
            <isset property="maven.repo.local"/>
        </condition>
        <echo>maven.repo.local=${maven.repo.local}</echo>
        <artifact:localRepository id="local.repository" path="${maven.repo.local}"/>
        <artifact:pom file="pom.xml" id="maven.project"/>
        <artifact:dependencies pathId="compile.classpath" filesetId="compile.fileset" useScope="compile">
            <pom refid="maven.project"/>
            <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
        </artifact:dependencies>
        <artifact:dependencies pathId="test.classpath" filesetId="test.fileset" useScope="test">
            <pom refid="maven.project"/>
            <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
        </artifact:dependencies>
        <artifact:dependencies pathId="runtime.classpath" filesetId="runtime.fileset" useScope="runtime">
            <pom refid="maven.project"/>
            <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
        </artifact:dependencies>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>seamjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>seamjpa</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>seam-jpa</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <seam.version>2.2.0.GA</seam.version>
        <jsf.version>1.2_12</jsf.version>
        <richfaces.version>3.3.1.GA</richfaces.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.4.2</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: If you are looking for dependency management feature in Ant, will you consider Ivy? I am a Maven user myself, but I heard quite some praise for Ivy, but seldom for maven-ant-task.  Ivy is using Maven repository itself

Comment: First I tried Ivy, but i did n't get good document to complete. Then only I started using maven-ant-task. Is there any helpful documentation on implementing Ivy?

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the references to maven-ant-tasks jar,

```
-    <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="Lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
+    <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />

-        <javac ... classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath"/>
+        <javac ... classpathref="compile.classpath"/>

-                <path refid="classpath"/>
+                <path refid="runtime.classpath"/>

-                 classpath="Lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3   .jar"/>
+                 classpath="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>
```

See also [usage examples](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html) in the docs including [bootstrapping via ant](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/maven-3/trunk/build.xml) that probably has useful examples.